# zipping two differently sized lists to make dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following two differently sized lists and want to combine them to a dictionary using `zip()` function.

```
stocks = ['CAT', 'IBM', 'MSFT']
prices = [20, 30, 40, 21, 31, 41, 22, 32, 42, 23, 33, 43]
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
from itertools import cycle
ziplist = []
ziplist.append(dict(zip(cycle(stocks), prices)))
```

I'm getting output as:

```
[{'CAT': 23, 'IBM': 33, 'MSFT': 43}]
```

My expected output should be a list with multiple dicts:

```
[{'CAT': 20, 'IBM': 30, 'MSFT': 40}, {'CAT': 21, 'IBM': 31, 'MSFT': 41}, {'CAT': 22, 'IBM': 32, 'MSFT': 42}, {'CAT': 23, 'IBM': 33, 'MSFT': 43}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `cycle` will not allow you to see the divisions.  Instead loop the calculable length.  You can use an iterator to keep track of where you are in the price list:

#### Code:

```
prices_iter = iter(prices)
data = [dict(zip(stocks, prices_iter)) for i in range(len(prices) // len(stocks))]
```

#### Test Code:

```
stocks = ['CAT', 'IBM', 'MSFT']
prices = [20, 30, 40, 21, 31, 41, 22, 32, 42, 23, 33, 43]

prices_iter = iter(prices)
data = [dict(zip(stocks, prices_iter)) for i in range(len(prices) // len(stocks))]

print(data)
```

#### Results:

```
[
    {'IBM': 30, 'MSFT': 40, 'CAT': 20}, 
    {'IBM': 31, 'MSFT': 41, 'CAT': 21}, 
    {'IBM': 32, 'MSFT': 42, 'CAT': 22}, 
    {'IBM': 33, 'MSFT': 43, 'CAT': 23}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
stocks = ['CAT', 'IBM', 'MSFT']
prices = [20, 30, 40, 21, 31, 41, 22, 32, 42, 23, 33, 43]

[dict(zip(stocks,prices[i:i+len(stocks)])) for i in range(0,len(prices),len(stocks))]
```

Answer (score 2):

create an iterator out of `prices`, then build the sub-dirs the proper number of times, picking a value at a time with `next`:

```
stocks = ['CAT', 'IBM', 'MSFT']
prices = [20, 30, 40, 21, 31, 41, 22, 32, 42, 23, 33, 43]

price_iter = iter(prices)

result = [{x:next(price_iter,0) for x in stocks} for _ in range(len(prices)//len(stocks)) ]
```

(in that case, if `prices` is too short, `next` yields 0 as a default value thanks to the second argument)